# Why does my bash script not work? ("command not found")

Tags: bash, ubuntu-11.04, bash-scripting

I wrote a very simple script that looks like that:

```
$ cat pack.sh
#!/bin/bash
cd log
rm development.log
cd ..
tar zcvf my_tar_ball.tar.gz *
```

But, it doesn't work:

```
$ pack.sh
pack.sh: command not found
```

`which bash` returns `/bin/bash`, and `pack.sh` is executable:

```
$ ls -ll pack.sh 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 misha misha 75 2012-02-04 22:11 pack.sh
```

What could be the problem?

(BTW, `source pack.sh` does work!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you did not put the scripts directory in your `PATH`(which is a environment variable), and . (the current directory) is not in the `PATH` either, you can activate the script like this:

```
$ ./pack.sh
```

Comment: Ignore my answer, @kev updated their answer To add to kev's answer, the reason why it doesn't work without ./ if front of it is because the current directory is not in $PATH.